# Notation for Clebsch-Gordan Coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, tensor-calculus

I just want to get some clarity a simple point regarding simultaneous eigenkets of angular momentum operators. With regards to simultaneous eigenstates of angular momentum operators, we have that $$J^2_1,~J^2_2,J_{1z}~~~\text{and }~~J_{2z}$$ have simultaneous eigenket $|j_1 j_2; m_1 m_2 \rangle$ and $J^2, J_{1}^2, J_{2}^2$ and $J_{z}$ has simultaneous eigenket $|j_1 j_2; j m \rangle$.

Am I correct in stating that the one eigenket is really a tensor product i.e. $$| j_1 j_2; m_1 m_2 \rangle = | j_1 m_1 \rangle \otimes |j_2, m_2 \rangle.$$

Hence would it be valid to write the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient as $\langle j_1 j_2; j m| (| j_1 m_1 \rangle \otimes | j_2, m_2 \rangle )$?

Answer (score 3):

Your notation is a little redundant as you list $j_1$ and $j_2$ twice.  Technically it is correct and it is also correct to write
$$
\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle=\vert j_1m_1\rangle\otimes \vert 2_1m_2\rangle
\, .
$$

If I may suggest:

Take the state $\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle$ and expand it in terms of the coupled states $\vert JM\rangle$:
\begin{align}
\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle=\sum_{J(M)}
\vert JM\rangle \langle JM\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle\, .
\end{align}
The coefficient $\langle JM\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle$ is the Clebsch.  Note that the sum over $M$ is actually just formal since the CG is $0$ unless $M=m_1+m_2$.

Because matrix elements of $\hat J_\pm$ and $\hat J_z$ can always be chosen to be real, the CG can also always chosen to be real, so that
$$
\langle JM\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle= \langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert JM\rangle
$$
and therefore 
$$
\vert JM\rangle = \sum_{j_1m_1j_2m_2}
\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle \langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert JM\rangle\, .
$$
Writing the CG in this way emphasizes it's an overlap from which several properties immediately follow, like
\begin{align}
\sum_{JM} \vert \langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert JM\rangle\vert^2&=\delta_{m_1+m_2,M}\, ,\\
\sum_{j_1m_1j_2m_2}
\vert  \langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert JM\rangle\vert^2&=\delta_{m_1+m_2,M}\, ,
\end{align}
as well as orthogonality properties such as
\begin{align}
\sum_{J'M'JM} \langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert JM\rangle 
\langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert J'M'\rangle =\delta_{JJ'}\delta_{MM'}
\delta_{m_1+m_2,M}
\end{align}

---

Edit: The CGs are real because:

1. The state $\vert J,M=J\rangle $ is killed by $J_+$.  Write this state as
   $$
   \vert J,M=J\rangle=\sum_{m_1m_2}\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle
   \langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2 \vert JM\rangle
   $$
   and act on this using $\hat J_+$.  The result is a recursion relation  for 
   the CG which contains real coefficients since the matrix elements of $J_+$ are real.  The CGs must satisfy this and so can be chosen as real.
2. Once you have the highest weight $\vert J,M=J\rangle$ state as a *real* linear combination of $\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle$, one gets the remaining $\vert JM\rangle$ states by lowering with $\hat J_-$.  Since the matrix elements of $\hat J_-$ are real, it follows that the CGs will also be real.

As an example, consider the state
$$
\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle = \vert 1,1/2;1,-1/2\rangle 
\langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle + 
\vert 1,1/2;0,1/2\rangle 
\langle 1,1/2;0,1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\, .
$$
Act on it with $\hat J_+$ to get
$$
0=\vert 1,1/2;1,1/2\rangle \langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle
+\sqrt{2}\vert 1,1/2;1,1/2\rangle\langle 1,1/2;0,1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle
$$
from which the ratio of the CG's can be obtained from
\begin{align}
\vert 1,1/2;1,1/2\rangle\langle 1,1/2;0,1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\vert 1,1/2;1,1/2\rangle \langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\, ,\\
\langle 1,1/2;0,1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\
\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\sqrt{2}=\langle 1,1\vert \hat J_+\vert 1,0\rangle$.

Now the CGs must satisfy 
$$
\vert\langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\vert^2+ 
\vert\langle 1,1/2;0,1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\vert^2=1\, .
$$
Using (1) we can rewrite the above as
\begin{align}
&\vert\langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\vert^2+ 
\frac{1}{2}\vert\langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\vert^2\\
&\quad =\frac{3}{2}\vert\langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle\vert^2=1\, .
\end{align}
with solution 
$$
\langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
$$
where the phase of $\langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle$ has been chosen to be $+1$.  Clearly (1) then implies $\langle 1,1/2;1,-1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle=-1/\sqrt{3}$, which is also real.

Once you have $\vert J,M=J\rangle$, acting with $\hat J_-$ produces a recursion between the different CGs with coefficients depending on the matrix elements of $\hat J_-$, which are real, so the solutions of the recursions that give the CGs will also be real.

Comment: Thanks. The notation is used in Sakurai, although he does supress the $j_1 j_2$ further on in the text. Anyway, I understand your reasoning except for how $\hat{J}_{pm}$ and $\hat{J}_z$ implies that CG can be chosen to be real?

Comment: Shouldn't the second term in your example after you act on $| 1/2, 1/2 \rangle$ with $J_{+}$ be $$0 = ...+ \sqrt{2} |1, 1/2; 1, 1/2 \rangle \langle 1,1/2;0, 1/2 | 1/2, 1/2 \rangle?$$ Also, how are what we did with $J_{+}$ imply that CG $\langle 1 1/2; 1 , 1/2 | 1/2 , 1/2 \rangle$ is real?

Comment: You use $\langle 1,1/2;1,1/2\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle$ when you state "As the CG..." I don't see where you have this CG before that?

Comment: Thanks. But how do you use normalization to imply that it is real with phase $+1$?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Great answer. Why do you have to choose the phase to be $+1$, are you implying that $\left< 1, 1/2; 1, -1/2| 1/2, 1/2 \right> = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not necessarily true if you don't?

Comment: @Alex  You could choose this CG to be $-\sqrt{2/3}$ is you wanted, and all the other CGs connected to this one by recursion would have a $-$ sign.  You could even choose the phase to be $+i$ so this CG is $i\sqrt{2/3}$, and all other CGs connected to this one by recursion would have an extra $i$... but why make life complicated?  It's like normalizing a wavefunction... you can choose the normalization constant to have a factor of $i$ in it, but why?  The choice $+1$ is the most convenient.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That makes sense, I guess it the usage of the word 'phase' that threw me off, usually I associate that with a quantum state rather that a complex number which the CG is.